# Programmatically insert rows to UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a CoreData entity which I need to populate the value of each objects into a table view cell. In the storyboard, I can add rows and change the style of my cells individually, but in this case I'm dealing with cells based on my number of objects and I have to programmatically insert rows and change the cell style.

[image]

I'm guessing that I need a foreach loop with the code to insert rows programmatically. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you explain? Do you have a reference of what do you want? Can you explain some use cases? From the question description one cannot understand exactly what are you asking.

Comment: @Adeel What I want to do is to add cells with the object's value, name and score. Because I have many objects, I would need a loop to add cells.

Comment: You just need to fetch the objects from coredata using predicates. Then in the _cellForRow:_ method you'll decide which kind of cell you should return. If you want to group cells of specific types together then you may use multiple sections. If you want to use one section only then you may query the objects from coredata based on the attributes and add them in an array. What have you tried so far and what problem are you unable to solve?

Comment: @Adeel I know how to fetch data from coredata into array, but I'm not sure how to create the cells. Yes, I only need one section.

Comment: @Adeel well, so far I've tried adding `cell.textLabel.text = @"Name";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Score: 0";` into the cellForRow: method. I'm just trying out to see whether I can create one cell, then I move on to creating multiple cells.

Comment: Have you worked with UITableViews before? Do you know what does UITableViewDataSource mean?

Comment: The thing is that there's a mechanism of how cells are added to tableViews. You first tell the dataSource how many sections and how many cells are there in each section.

Comment: @Adeel yeah, but not programmatically and with datasources. I've used data source in C# DataGridView, but not in iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement `UITableViewDataSource`. See the [API Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource) for more information. 
When using Core Data with `UITableView`s you might also want to take a look at `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Comment: Yup, you guys are all right. I'm kinda stuck with C# Windows Form's method of populating data into grid views (In this case, table view). Didn't know the method of adding cells is so complicated for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use UITableViewDataSource methods. Add the dataSource protocol to your class and conform to it. The method you are looking for is:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

You probably will also want to conform to UITableViewDelegate protocol.

Do something like this:

```
class MyClass: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
//Do your thing
}

//Conform to rest of the delegate and datasource methods too. Click on UITableViewDataSource to see the documentation
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int` and `return` your objects array's count, then set a reuse identifier for the cell and add the code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") //replace "Cell" with your identifier
    cell.textLabel = yourTitleArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.detailTextLabel = yourSubtitleArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell!
}
```

Don't forget to replace `yourTitleArray` and `yourSubtitleArray` with your arrays.